# Why doesn't defining a static enum cause a link time error?

Tags: c++, c++11, enums

I have used enum variable as static but not defined outside the class.

```
enum log_level_e
{
    error=1,
    warning,
    debug,
    trace
};


class Logger
{
    private:

        static mutex logger_mutex;

        Logger() {}
        ~Logger() {}
        Logger (const Logger& source);
        Logger& operator== (const Logger& source);
        static log_level_e loglevel;
        // functions and all
};
```

Ideally, it should give a link time error, but it's working fine without error. Why is it so? I am using a C++11 compiler.

Comment: Why would you get a linker error? log_level_e is defined right there?

Comment: What link-time error? You've defined the enum. There's nothing missing here. They're not classes you know, just a more civilised #define.

Comment: it's declared not defined.  If you are right then why we need to define for this - static mutex logger_mutex; outside the class.

Comment: If i am not wrong static variable .. declare inside and defined outside the class.

Comment: Do you actually read or set Logger::loglevel anywhere?  It could be that it's unusued, and therefore not linked.

Comment: An enumeration is like a datatype. Think about a typedef, would you try to make it static?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because nobody is using it and the linker does not attempt to look for it.
This gives you the "desired" error

```
class Logger
{
    public:
        Logger() {
            loglevel = warning;    
        }
        ~Logger() {}
    private:
        Logger (const Logger& source);
        Logger& operator== (const Logger& source);
        static log_level_e loglevel;
        // functions and all
};
```